# Update GTS Part Classification in background

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-apo

I'm looking for a way to update Part Classification data programmatically.  This is the data on the Classification tab of transaction /sapsll/product_03.  Classification data is stored in table /SAPSLL/PRCTSC.

I found function module /SAPSLL/PRCTSC_DB_WRITE but it basically just does a direct table update.  I'd like to take advantage of the validation behind the Classification screen.  Anyone know of a function module to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was the class `/SAPSLL/CL_PR`.